# Is it possible to move a report from Salesforce production to sandbox?

Tags: salesforce

I want to move a report that is on production to a sandbox. I do not want to refresh the sandbox as there is data on the sandbox that is not on production.
Is there a way to move the report to the sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can migrate a report from production to a sandbox using:

1. ANT migration tool
2. Change Set
3. Workbench (open source) : Migrate -> Deploy menu option

Comment: Just a note, these methods do not apply to Personal Reports that your users create for their own use. As far as I know, personal reports cannot be moved from sandbox to sandbox/production, and the only way to move them from production into a sandbox would be to refresh the sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

First check the reports you want to move in 'Unfiled Public Reports' otherwise move it to this folder.
Then add it to the change set and upload the change set to sandbox and deploy it.